# how to fix 404 in django, problem with urls

Tags: django

Working on simple api. All seemed fine, but after pressing the button, script is suppose to send the data to model. By now it shos me the error 404 and previously append_slash but I set it to false and still not working. I'm fresh in this framework. Appreciate for advice.

Just noticed that after clicking button my http bar goes to /index which does not exist. My form template is located on raw localhost. How can I pass the data then?

views.py

```
def index(request):
    url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&apikey=My key is here'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MovieForm(data=request.POST)
        form.save()

    else:
        form = MovieForm()
        movies = Movie.objects.all() #// fetch all objects
        movies_data = []  #//// array for movies and their details
        for movie in movies:
            r = requests.get(url.format(movie)).json() #// gets details from api
            movies_main = {
                'title': movie.title,
                'director': r['Director'],
                'rate': r['imdbRating'],
            }
            movies_data.append(movies_main)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'movies_data': movies_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'movies/movies.html', context)
```

main urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('movies.urls'))
]
```

app urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

Comment: which url you try?

Comment: i use the empty one which is index

Comment: I mean url like `127.0.0.1/` or `127.0.0.1/index`

Comment: How are you calling it from your template?

Comment: I access the web by localhost:8000/index/ (double slash) and after clicking the button it shows the error. The name of template is movies.html